# Understanding Arithemtic Manipulation for Geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider $\alpha$ as a unit speed curve where $\alpha = x(u,v)$. Note: $u$ and $v$ serve as a coordinate patch here. Then, we have

$\alpha^{'} = u^{'}x_u + v^{'}x_v$ as a result of the chain rule. The next part is that I have trouble understanding.

Let, $\theta$ denote the angle between $a^{'}$ and $x_u$. How does this imply that then, 
$\alpha^{'} = cos \theta \frac{x_u}{\sqrt{E}} + sin \theta \frac{x_v}{\sqrt{G}}$, where $E$ and $G$ are the metrics defined in Euclidian space i.e. $E=x_u \cdot x_u$ and $G= x_v \cdot x_v$.

Thank you!

Comment: The title seems misleading.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct if and only if $F=x_u\cdot x_v=0$. Then it's the usual representation of a unit vector as a linear combination of an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I used your textbook for my Linear Algebra class at Duke University